# How to create a water droplet (half-sphere) on a rock (quartz) surface

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, vmd, packmol

I am to Equilibrate a uniformly distributed spc water molecules at 300k in 50x50x50 box. Water density is taken to be 1000kg/m3. Simulate the system in the NVT ensemble. The spc water is modeled using the CLAYFF force field.

*** in my calculations of numbers water molecules for the box I had 4177 molecules.***

Out of the equilibrated spc water molecules above, create a half-sphere of radius 26A to depict water droplets. And this water droplet has 946 spc water molecules.

My challenge is to create the water droplets

Comment: Take a look [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6174/24), similar quation.